# How do I create data binding between highcharts and Polymer 1.0

Tags: highcharts, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having a hard time getting the data binding to work between Highcharts and Polymer 1.0. Especially with multiple series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wrapper for the Highcharts Container with data binding derivatives. However there is a Highcharts Component already created that does this with realtime support: https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart.

And a live demo at: http://avdaredevil.github.io/highcharts-chart/